# Copying files from one folder to another using batch

Tags: batch-file, file-copying

I'm trying to copy some files from one directory to two other directories, using batch.

First i'm making 3 directories and after that, i want to copy the following files to backup1 and backup2.
The files are named 010101.txt - 300101.txt (To backup1) and 010102.txt - 300102.txt (backup2).

```
mkdir backup1
mkdir backup2
mkdir backup3
copy 1.txt C:\User\Test\Backup1
copy 2.txt C:\User\Test\Backup2
```

I guess i have to use wildcard somehow, but if i write ?????1.txt and ?????2.txt i get an syntex error.

Comment: Are those ranges the only files in the dir?

Comment: Are you showing 4 files in `010101.txt - 300101.txt and 010102.txt - 300102.txt` because if they are ranges then they overlap.

Comment: There are those 60 .txt files and some few .bat files and the backup directories in there as well. Was that what you meant ?

Comment: No it is files.
There is a file called 010101.txt and every single number up to 300101.txt and another 30 .txt files which end in 02.
Did I make myself clear enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "C:\Temp\copytest"
set "b1=C:\Temp\Backup1"
set "b2=C:\Temp\Backup2"
for /l %%a in (1,1,300102) do (
  set num=%%a
  if %%a GTR 10000 if %%a LSS 100000 set num=0%%a
  if !num:~-1! EQU 1 (
     if exist !num!.txt echo copy !num!.txt %b1%
  ) ELSE (
     if !num:~-1! EQU 2 (
       if exist !num!.txt echo copy !num!.txt %b2%
     )
  )
)
```

Change paths where applicable. Remove the echos after verifying the output is correct to do the actual copy.

**Edit: Simpler way**

```
Copy *1.txt "C:\User\Test\Backup1"
Copy *2.txt "C:\User\Test\Backup2"
```

Comment: Hey Matt  Thank you for your answer, but this is to extensive for what i'm looking for. 
This is for a school assignment, where we are learning to program. I have to be able to explain what I am doing. 
According to my teacher it should be possible to do while just using the "copy" command and "wildcard". 
I just cant wrap my head around how to do it.
Thank you again for your time !

Comment: That solved it ! I've actually tried that before, but left out the ". Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR %%b IN (1 2) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" ^| find /i "%%b.txt" '
   ) DO (
  XCOPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "c:\user\test\backup%%b\" >nul
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I've assumed you want all files in the directory that contain `1.txt` to be copied to ...\backup1 and those that contain `2.txt` to ...\backup2.

I used my current directory for testing. You'd need to change the value assigned to 'sourcedir' to suit yourself.

Note that the `xcopy` will create the destination directory if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! Found a simpler solution though. But thank you for your time.

Comment: first I want to create backup folder with date&time and after that I want to past files on it , how i can do this?